# Making an @get() request using a variable - bottle.py

Tags: python, bottle

I have a function that gets a random string, then I have a @get request to get the random string as a request, however, it turned out to be harder than I thought. How can I make this work?

here's a snippet of the code

```python
link_id = ''

def confirm_email(email, name):
    global link_id
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    link_id = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(100))


@get('/' + link_id)
def lnkoconfirm():
    global name
    global email
    global password
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Don't use `global`. Instead learn how to call a function and pass parameters.

Comment: With that said, what exactly do you want your `@get()` route to do? What should it return in its response?

Comment: And what is the purpose of the `confirm_email()` function. You declare it to take two parameters, but then you do nothing with those parameters. You should figure out what these parameters are for and do something with them.

Comment: sorry, i havnt really explained this well, but i am basically making it where it generates a random string of numbers for a link, it then send that link to the users email adress, when they click on it, i want the website to then add the account. but becasue you click the link through your emails, the variables get reset

Comment: so it all works apart from when the user clicks the web address from the email, the program forgets what the randomly generated string of numbers is, so it cant get the go a head to create the account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dynamic routing.

https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#request-routing

```py
@get('/<link_id>')
def lnkoconfirm(link_id):
    global name
    global email
    global password
```

Comment: We should also discourage the OP from using `global` and point them towards more structured ways of solving the problem. For example, you can show how to pass `link_id` to another function.